# RST,ACK vs RST - Connection reset by peer vs Success

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

There are two processes: client and server.

Client connects to server and waits on recv(). If server is killed with abort() function or kill terminate signal after accept() then I see in Wireshark that RST,ACK is sent to client by OS of server and client recv() function gives error Connection reset by peer.

However if server exit() after accept() then there is sent RST to client (without ACK) and recv() of client returns 0 and errno is not set.

What is the difference between RST,ACK and RST so that for the first time it results with Connection reset by peer and for the second case there is no error at all?

I'm using Linux 3.11.

Comment: recv() returns zero when a FIN has been received. If an ACK has been received it returns -1/ECONNRESET. Please check your observations.